# Approximating money among people only knowing the total amount among them using reoccuring pattern?

Tags: statistics

There is a web game called "Mafiaenshevn" where players can earn money and steal from each other. The amount you can steal depends on your rank within the game. Each person has a business which makes a semi-fixed amount of money every hour, although this can go up and down each day. Every 2 hours, you have the opportunity to select multiple "victims" from whom you can steal. However, there is a limit to the total percentage of money you can steal, so you need to consider how many people to target. Some individuals may have more money, while others may have less.

For instance, if you have five victims and a total of 250% to steal, this percentage will be divided among all the victims. As a result, you will steal 50% from each person. If one of the victims has no money, the 50% allotted to them goes to waste. In such cases, it would be more beneficial to target only four victims.

Unfortunately, there is no way to know exactly how much money each person has. The only clue you have is the amount you have stolen and the individuals present during each instance. With enough data and by observing patterns, it might be possible to estimate the approximate wealth of each person. How would i go on solving this problem and get an approximate on how much each victim has?

My current process is to save the data of each instance to a .json, an entry would look something like this:

```
[
  {
    "date": "02/06/2023 13:30",
    "victims": [
      "Poetry",
      "Reawaken",
      "LordCommander",
      "Kleopatra",
      "Dondonny"
    ],
    "associates":[
      {"name": "Grætten", "bullets": 1, "percentage": 256}
    ],
    "total_percentage":423,
    "earnings": 369765881  
  },
  {
    "date": "02/06/2023 16:30",  
    "victims": [
      "LordCommander",
      "Dondonny",
      "TanjaLaila",
      "Johnernn",
      "Fraser"
    ],
    "associates":[
      {"name": "Grætten", "bullets": 1, "percentage": 256}
    ],
    "total_percentage": 423,
    "earnings": 246810086
  }
]
```

Now i need a formula / approach to solve this, is there any statistical formula or principle is can use here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand the context here. When you say that you distribute the 250% among five players, does that mean that you steal 50% of wealth from each, because that sounds pretty harsh. So I wanted to make sure I understand it properly.

Comment: @Keen You do not directly steal from the overall wealth of each person, but rather from their business which generate some revenue every hour, but overall yes, you steal 50% of what that business has made that hour IF the person (owner) has not claimed it already. The owner is able to take out some cash every whole hour (e.g 14:00, 17:00), if the owner has not taken it out after half an hour, other players are able to steal from them. You can go on their profile and check when they were last online, if they have not been online the past hour, they have not been able to claim it, so others can.